# A curve internally tangent to a sphere of radius $R$ has curvature at least $1/R$ at the point of tangency

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature, curves

Suppose $a$ is an arc length-parametrized space curve with the property that 
$\|a(s)\| \leq \|a(s_0)\| = R$ for all $s$ sufficiently close to $s_0$. Prove that 
$k(s_0) \geq 1/R$.

So, I was going to consider the function $f(s) = \|a(s)\|^2$ but then the hint asks what we know about $f''(s_0)$? I am confused on how to link the two together and show from there that the curvature of $k(s_0) \geq 1/R$.

I know that we should use the second derivative test to see the local minima or maxima thus giving us if the curve points upward or downward, but I am a little lost at where to begin. I was told that $f(s_0)$ is constant, why? How come $f(s)$ is not a constant function here?

Comment: See for example http://mathoverflow.net/questions/395/reading-list-for-basic-differential-geometry - oops, that was for the old question, which just has vanished.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize you could only ask 1 question every 20 mins and I am really struggling with this current problem! Thanks for the link!                   @DietrichBurde do you have any insight on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Some intermediate hints:

1. We are given that $\Vert a(s) \Vert \leq \Vert a(s_0)\Vert$ for all $s$ near $s_0$.  Squaring both sides tells us that $f(s) \leq f(s_0)$ for all $s$ near $s_0$. In other words, $s = s_0$ is a local max for the function $f$.  What does that imply about $f''(s_0)$?
2. You should compute $f''(s_0)$ as the hint says.  This means that you'll have to compute $f'(s)$, then its derivative $f''(s)$, then finally plug in $f''(s_0)$.  To compute these derivatives, you should use that $f(s) = \Vert a(s) \Vert^2 = \langle a(s), a(s) \rangle$, and use the product rule for inner products:
   $$\frac{d}{ds}\langle F(s), G(s) \rangle = \langle F'(s), G(s) \rangle + \langle F(s), G'(s) \rangle.$$
3. Finally, once you've computed $f''(s)$ and also used Hint 1, you should get an inequality.  At this point, you might want to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality
   $$\left|\langle v,w \rangle\right| \leq \Vert v \Vert \Vert w \Vert.$$
   You'll also want to remember that since $a(s)$ is unit speed, we have $\Vert a'(s) \Vert = 1$ for all $s$.

Comment: This makes complete sense thanks!! However, I just have one question. When I solve all of this out I am getting k(s0) > -4 - R. After finding the second derivative I have:
f''(s0) = 2<a''(s0), 2a'(s0), a(s0)> 
Then We know that f''(s0) < 0 because of the second derivative test so we can use Cauchy to have 
0 < || 2<a''(s0), 2a'(s0), a(s0)> || 
when we rewrite that through Cauchy we get 
0 < 2*[ ||a''(s0)|| * ||2*a'(s0)|| * ||a(s0)|| 
How do you get +1/R
I keep getting -4 - R

Comment: I am unsure about the derivative I am getting. Also, when using cauchy are we going to use the dot product or factor with the two magnitudes ||v|| and ||w|| which then is greater than 0 and then move the terms over?

Comment: @Unkle: Your second derivative $f''(s_0)$ looks odd to me. For instance, why does the inner product have three terms? If $f(s) = \langle a(s), a(s) \rangle$, then $$f'(s) = \langle a'(s), a(s) \rangle + \langle a(s), a'(s) \rangle,$$ yes?

Comment: right that is what I had for f'(s) but then we need to do the same d/ds⟨F(s),G(s)⟩=⟨F′(s),G(s)⟩+⟨F(s),G′(s)⟩.

Comment: So I had f'(s) = <a'(s) + a(s), a'(s) + a(s)>

Comment: @Unkle: $\langle a,b \rangle + \langle c,d \rangle \neq \langle a+c, b+d \rangle$.

Comment: However, $\langle a,b \rangle + \langle b,a\rangle = \langle a,b \rangle + \langle a,b\rangle = 2\langle a,b\rangle$, if that helps.  Anyway, that's all for me.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think is going on, I'll let you fill in the details.
The relevant definitions are all included here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_space_curves

Because $a$ is parametrized by the arc-length, the curvature at a point $s$ is simply $\kappa(s) = ||a''(s)||$. Now imagine a curve $\gamma$ (also parametrized by the arc-length) whose image is the intersection of a sphere of radius $R$, and a plane passing through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and such that $\gamma(s_{0}) = a(s_{0})$ (and if you want $\gamma'(s_{0})= a'(s_{0})$); in this case the curvature of $\gamma$ at $s_{0}$ (and at any other point for that matter) is simply $\kappa(s_{0}) = 1/R$.

Now we know that $||a(s)|| \leq ||a(s_{0})|| = R$ for $s$ close to $s_{0}$. If you think about this geometrically, this means that near $s_{0}$, the curve $a$ does not leave the sphere of radius $R$; in fact it may even curve inward. Therefore, it is not too hard to see that $||a''(s_{0})|| \geq ||\gamma''(s_{0})||$, or in other words, $\kappa(s_{0}) \geq 1/R$.

Comment: I am confused at "γ(s0)=a(s0) (and if you want γ′(s0)=a′(s0)); in this case the curvature of γ at s0 (and at any other point for that matter) is simply κ(s0)=1/R." How come this is so? Thank you for your answer I greatly appreciate it!!

Comment: The "therefore it is not too hard to see that" is precisely what the OP is trying to prove. What you have given is not a proof, but an intuitive explanation as to why the fact in question ought to be true.

Comment: Well, first consider just the space curve $\gamma$, whose image lies in the intersection of a plane and a sphere of radius $R$. We can write down $\gamma$ using coordinates on the plane and with arc-length parameter $s$ as: $x(s) = R \text{cos}(s/R)$, $y = R \text{sin}(s/R)$. So $||\gamma''(s)||^2 = x''(s)^2 + y''(s)^2 = 1/R^2$. In other words, $\kappa(s) = 1/R$. The other two conditions I added were just to make $\gamma$ and $a$ tangent to each other at $s_{0}$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  I mean that you have not proven why $\Vert a''(s_0) \Vert \geq \Vert \gamma''(s_0) \Vert$ holds.  Your reason why it ought to hold geometrically is persuasive, but I think one can be much more precise.

Comment: Note: "Here's what I think is going on, I'll let you fill in the details."

Comment: @unknownymous thanks that makes more sense now, I like your explanation! With regard to the hint f''(s0) what is the purpose of relating it to f(s)= ||a(s)||^2? What does that accomplish? How would a second derivative test help here?

Comment: @JesseMadnick with 1) It would mean that the curve is decreasing since it is at a local maxima.
2) so if f(s) = ||a(s)||^2 then a(s) = ⟨a(s),a(s)⟩ right. 
I am a bit confused on the derivation of this with regards to f(s0). Thanks for the hints!!