# If a curve lies in a circle of radius $r$, show there is a point at which the curvature $|k(s)|\geq 1/r$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves, plane-geometry

I am self studying curves and came across this problem:

> Let $\alpha: I \to R^2$ be a simple smooth closed plane curve.
>
> i) If the curve lies inside a circle of radius $r$, show there is a point at which the curvature $|k(s)|\geq1/r$.
>
> ii) If $0<|k(s)|\leq c$ for some constant $c$. Then show that the length of the curve is bounded below by $\frac {2 \pi}{c}$.

Any help would be appreciated, this looks intuitively obvious to me as the curvature of a circle is 1/r so there must be a point on that curve with greater curvature as it is inside the circle, but how to prove it mathematically? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have tried to use the fact that $<\alpha(s),\alpha(s)> \leq r^2$ and do some algebra or use serret frenet out of it but to no avail. (by < , > i mean dot product)

Comment: We want to find a function on your curve whose derivative along the curve is $0$ only when the curvature of the curve is large. Since the curve is closed, the derivative will be $0$ somewhere.

I think one such function is to take the inner product between two vectors: the normal at your point, and the vector pointing from the center of the circle at your point.

Comment: related: math.stackexchange.com/questions/922606/a-curve-internally-tangent-to-a-sphere-of-radius-r-has-curvature-at-least-1-r

Comment: Related (with a direct link): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922606/a-curve-internally-tangent-to-a-sphere-of-radius-r-has-curvature-at-least-1-r